# group by code and organize data in columns according to the patient's age range mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

I currently have a table called activities_procedures which contains all the procedures that a patient has been performed, the idea is to be able to organize in columns according to the age range if the patient had the procedure performed in that age range.

According to the age of the patient belongs to a life cycle for this then we have a table called cycles which contains the following fields: id,cycle

| ID | Ciclo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | early childhood |
| 2 | infancy |
| 3 | adolescence |
| 4 | youth |
| 5 | adulthood |
| 6 | old age |

i have a table called cupsrutas which contains the following fields: id,nom_servicio, cups, ciclos_id. in this table i define those services that i want to validate according to the life cycle of the patient.

| ID | nom_servicio | cups | ciclos_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | Health care by general practice | 890201 | 2 |
| 30 | Health care by nurse practitioner | 890205 | 2 |
| 31 | Oral health care by dental professional | 890203 | 2 |

it must be taken into account that each procedure has some age ranges where it is mandatory that the procedure is done, for that reason I named a table called CUPS_AGES which contains id, age, period (years as A or months as M) and the id of the cups as foranea.

| ID | AGE | PERIOD | cupsrutas_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2127 | 6 | A | 29 |
| 2128 | 8 | A | 29 |
| 2129 | 10 | A | 29 |
| 2130 | 7 | A | 30 |
| 2131 | 9 | A | 30 |
| 2132 | 11 | A | 30 |
| 2133 | 6 | A | 31 |
| 2134 | 7 | A | 31 |
| 2135 | 8 | A | 31 |
| 21236 | 9 | A | 31 |
| 2137 | 10 | A | 31 |
| 2138 | 11 | A | 31 |

according to these data then we can say that the procedure with id 29 that is in the table cupsrutas must be performed in the age ranges 6,8,10 years and the procedure with id 30 must be performed when the patient is 7,9,11 years old and the procedure with id 31 must be performed when the patient is 6,7,8,9,10,11 years old.

the idea is that according to the identification number search in the table activities_procedures and list the procedures and organize in columns according to the range [6,7,8,9,10,11] and also take into account whether the procedure is mandatory or not, to solve the problem perform the following query which works. but the idea is to automate it and make it work for the age ranges of the other cycles.

Early childhood [1 MONTH, 2-3 MONTHS, 4,5 MONTHS, 6-8 MONTHS, 9,11 MONTHS, 12,18 MONTHS 18,23 MONTHS, 24,29 MONTHS, 30,35 MONTHS, 3 YEARS, 4 YEARS, 5 YEARS].

INFANCY [6,7,8,9,10,11], ADOLESCENCE [12 A,13 A,14 A,15 A,16 A,17 A], YOUTH [18 A,19 A,20 A,21 A,22 A,23 A,24 A,25 A,26 A,27 A,28 A], ADULTHOOD [29-34 A, 35-39 A, 40-44 A,45-49 A, 50-54 A, 55,59 A ], OLD AGE [60-62 A, 63-65 A, 66-68 A, 69-71 A, 72-74 A, 75-77 A, 78-79 A, 80 YEARS OLD AND OVER], OLD AGE [60-62 A, 63-65 A, 66-68 A, 69-71 A, 72-74 A, 75-77 A, 78-79 A, 80 YEARS OLD AND OVER].

if I perform a search in the activities_procedures table filtering by ID number and with a join from the cupsrutas table I get the following results:

```
select cr.id,ap.cupcod,ap.actividad,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) as age_in_years from actividades_procedimientos as ap
    inner join cupsrutas cr on cr.cups = ap.cupcod
where ap.pacide = 1111564884 and cr.ciclos_id=2
order BY  ap.cupcod;
```

Query Result:

| CUPSRUTAID | CUPCOD | ACTIVIDAD | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 890201 | Health care by general medicine | 8 |
| 29 | 890201 | Health care by general medicine | 7 |
| 31 | 890203 | Oral health care by dentistry professional | 7 |

there are 3 records where one was made when the patient was 7 years old and 8 years old and the other was made when she was 7 years old.

the query I performed to be able to solve the problem is this:

```
select cr.id,ap.cupcod,ap.actividad,
       min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 6  THEN
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 6 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 6 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "6-M",
       min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 7  THEN
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 7 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 7 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "7-M",
       min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 8  THEN
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 8 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 8 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "8-M",
    min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 9  THEN
                 if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 9 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 9 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "9-M",
       min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 10  THEN
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 10 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 10 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "10-M",
       min(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ap.pacnac, ap.cardetfec) = 11  THEN
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 11 AND period = 'A') = 1, 1  ,2)
                ELSE
                    if(exists(SELECT * FROM CUPS_AGES ca where ca.cupsrutas_id = cr.id AND AGE = 11 AND period = 'A') = 1, 2  ,0)
                    END) as "11-M"
from actividades_procedimientos ap
         inner join cupsrutas cr on cr.cups =  ap.cupcod
where ap.pacide = 1111564884 AND cr.ciclos_id=2 group by ap.cupcod ;
```

I get this result:

| CUPSRUTAID | CUPCOD | ACTIVIDAD | 6-M | 7-M | 8-M | 9-M | 10-M | 11-M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 890201 | Health care by general medicine | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 31 | 890203 | Oral health care by dentistry professional | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

0 = does not exist in the table cups_ages and does not exist in the table activities_procedures
1= exists in the cups_ages table and the age exists in the activities_procedures table
2= age exists in the table activities_procedures and does not exist in the table cups_ages

So, for example, according to the above query for procedure 890201 we should mark it in age column 7 and 8 years and for procedure 890203 we should mark it in age column 7 years.
But as the procedure 890201 is only mandatory in 6,8,10 years then that is why in the column where the patient is 7 years old we put a 2 since it is not mandatory.
On the other hand, there are also some procedures that are done semiannually (every 6 months) or quinquennially.

Expected result with other user id and assuming it is a procedure(cups) where procedures are applied semi-annually.:

| CUPSRUTAID | CUPCOD | ACTIVIDAD | 6-M | 7-M | 8-M | 9-M | 10-M | 11-M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 890201 | Health care by general medicine | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 31 | 890203 | Oral health care by dentistry professional | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 34 | 997106 | Application of fluoride varnish | [2,1] | [1,] | [2,2] | [2,2] | [2,2] | [2,2] |

Comment: how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query needs

```
cr:  INDEX(ciclos_id, cups,  id)
ap:  INDEX(pacide, cupcod)
```

For that long query, do some kind of lookup based on `AGE` rather than go through nested `IFs`.